# Symfony Route with Slash (/) in parameter not working

Tags: symfony, url-routing, symfony6

I have a Symfony Route configured with annotations where I want the last parameter to allow for slashes in it.

```
#[Route('/getFtp/{customerName}/{taskId}/{domainName}', name: 'get_ftp', requirements: ['domainName' => '.+'])]
public function index(string $customerName, string $taskId, string $domainName): Response
```

According to documentation https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/routing.html#slash-characters-in-route-parameters this should work.

It works for

```
http://mgr2.example.com/getFtp/quadramedia/abcdef/http:
```

but not for

```
http://mgr2.example.com/getFtp/quadramedia/abcdef/http:%2F
```

Comment: The docs also state the following: `If the route defines several parameters and you apply this permissive regular expression to all of them, you might get unexpected results.`. Do you have any other requirements defined in yaml or other route configs. I just tried the above route locally and for me it works fine. So I'm assuming there might be some config you're missing.

Comment: I tried this in my Symfony 5.4.x project and it works. What Symfony version exactly are you using?

Comment: Does it work for http://mgr2.example.com/getFtp/quadramedia/abcdef/http%3A%2F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your exemple in my own project worked.

I tryied this url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/getFtp/thomas/23/http:%2F`

And then i dumped my param to be sure and got :

[image]

So, it is on your project that something is wrong.
I expect something like an other route is matching.
Try to define the route in yaml (or just on top of your controller) and put it **on top of all the other** to be completely sure that this is not working.

By the way, i tried your case in php 8.1 and Symfony 6.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably caused by a bad apache configuration.

As described [here](http://www.leakon.com/archives/865), the following parameters should be present in httpd.conf or in the VirtualHost config.

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Symfony 5.x versions. I would suggest take `domainName` as a request parameter in an argument. For example:

```
#[Route('/getFtp/{customerName}/{taskId}', name: 'get_ftp')]
public function index(string $customerName, string $taskId, Request $request): Response
{
  $domainName = $request->query->get('domainName');
  ...
}
```